# Date Range Order by Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date range that what I would like to populate another column by number based on the oldest to newest.

Example:

```
Date          Order
6/10/2017       5
6/2/2017        1
6/6/2017        3
6/4/2017        4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rank formula. I assume that you have 100 dates and your dates are there in column A and starting from row2. Then You have to enter the below formula in B2 cell and copy the same in next 100 cells. You will get the number.

```
=RANK(A2,$A$2:$A$100,1)
```

if you have more than 100, then change the number 100 in the above formula to the number that you have.